# How do I filter my states columns against a East/West parameter?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that has a column with different states. How do I filter those states from my parameter that has just East and West instead of individual states?

My query for state list is:

```
select distinct
state
from contract
```

my query for parameter is:

```
select distinct
case when  STATE = 'CA' or STATE = 'WA' or STATE = 'MO'
        or STATE = 'OR' or STATE = 'NV' or STATE = 'ID'
        or STATE = 'MT' or STATE = 'WY' or STATE = 'UT'
        or STATE = 'AZ' or STATE = 'CO' or STATE = 'NM'
        or STATE = 'ND' or STATE = 'SD' or STATE = 'NE'
        or STATE = 'KS' or STATE = 'OK' or STATE = 'TX'
        or STATE = 'LA' or STATE = 'AR' or STATE = 'IA'
        or STATE = 'MN' or STATE = 'HI' or STATE = 'AK' then 'West'

    when   STATE = 'MI' or STATE = 'OH' or STATE = 'PA'
        or STATE = 'NJ' or STATE = 'WI' or STATE = 'IL'
        or STATE = 'IN' or STATE = 'KY' or STATE = 'TN'
        or STATE = 'MS' or STATE = 'AL' or STATE = 'GA' 
        or STATE = 'FL' or STATE = 'SC' or STATE = 'NC'
        or STATE = 'VA' or STATE = 'WV' or STATE = 'MD'
        or STATE = 'DE' or STATE = 'CT' or STATE = 'RI' 
        or STATE = 'NY' or STATE = 'MA' or STATE = 'VT'
        or STATE = 'NH' or STATE = 'ME'  then 'East'
    else null end as 'Territory Selection'
from contracts
```

My parameter would show up as [All][West][East]. I thought if I set my filter as [State] IN [Territory Selection] it would filter the states as belonging to east or west but it's not working as expected. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set the parameter called 'EastWest' up with the checkbox 'allow null'.  Set up a simple query to get it's data for 'available values from a query' like:

   ```
   Select 'West' as Territory
   union
   Select 'East'
   ```
2. Create ANOTHER dataset like you did above already but put it in a CTE and reference the first parameter like so:

   ```
   With a as 
   (
   Select 
       State
   , case when  STATE in ('CA','WA', 'MO', 'OR' ,'NV' ,'ID','MT' ,'WY' ,'UT','AZ' ,'CO' ,'NM','ND' ,'SD' ,'NE'
           ,'KS' ,'OK' ,'TX','LA' ,'AR' ,'IA','MN' ,'HI' ,'AK') then 'West'
       when  State in ('MI' ,'OH' ,'PA','NJ' ,'WI' ,'IL','IN' ,'KY' ,'TN','MS' ,'AL' ,'GA','FL' ,'SC' ,'NC'
           ,'VA' ,'WV' ,'MD','DE' ,'CT' ,'RI','NY' ,'MA' ,'VT','NH' ,'ME')  then 'East'
       end as 'Territory Selection'
   from (State Listing)
   )
   Select State
   from a
   where [Territory Selection] = isnull(@EastWest,[Territory Selection])
   ```
3. Pay careful note to the predicate as it states essentially: "When variable is null, select everything by relating the column back to itself"
4. Create another variable that is 'hidden' call it 'states' and bind it to the above dataset you created.  You are basically taking one variable of something small and then getting the data you need from something actual that did not exist in a column before hand OR.... you needed a distinct label and not something listed for every instance of a state.
5. You now probably have a regular data set like

   ```
   Select (thing)
   from (real table)
   where states in (@states)
   ```